# Scrolling a superimposed element, disabling scrolling on body

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm attempting to write an image gallery for Javascript-enabled browsers.  The gallery displays thumbnails and redirects to the full photo, which is placed in a table containing navigation links and a caption.  The table is centered with fixed positioning, and an opaque division is sandwiched between the table and the normal page flow.  The scroll bar is then disabled on the body (the table tag itself is within the body tag).

My question is this: how can scrolling be enabled for the superimposed gallery when the window size is smaller than the size of the image and body scrolling is disabled?  I realize that HTML tables can't be scrolled on their own, but I have wrapped it in a division together with the opaque division.  Should I use absolute positioning for the gallery table instead of fixed positioning?

I know how to calculate window size, and I can compare it using Javascript with the element size, so I do know when this situation arises.

Answer (score 0):

Set the CSS on the 'superimposed' image, this will give it its own scroll bars:

```
imgDiv{
height: 10px;
width: 20px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: My images aren't fixed width; the table adjusts to accommodate them.  Also, I want to scroll the entire table, including navigation and caption.

Comment: I dont understand why you would need to scroll if the table adjusts to accomodate them. You could try setting Max Height and keeping the overflow:scroll? Sorry, Im not sure what the problem is exactly.